# Violin plot problem in Julia: Cannot use same x-positions for 2 datasets

Tags: julia, violin-plot

I use Julia Version 1.4.2 and want to make a violin plot, where I have two datasets A and B, which I want to plot using the same x-ticks. I want that data A is the left half of each x-position and B the right half.

Here a test example:

```
using StatsPlots
A=[rand(10), rand(12), rand(44)]
B=A./2
X=[1,2,3]
StatsPlots.violin(A,xticks=X,side=:left)
StatsPlots.violin!(B,xticks=X,side=:right)
```

When I run this, data A gets plotted as I wish, but data B is shifted. I would like that at x-position 1 there is A to the left and B to right to compare them next to each other. However, I get a plot where the data from B is at x-position 4-6 (without labelled ticks though):

[image: violin plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using a solution that works, but which is a bit ugly:

```
using StatsPlots
A=[rand(10), rand(12), rand(44)]
B=A./2
X=[[1],[2],[3]] #this is changed compared to my initial post

StatsPlots.violin(X[1],A[1],side=:left)
StatsPlots.violin!(X[1],B[1],side=:right)

for i=2:length(X)
    println(length(X))
    StatsPlots.violin!(X[i],A[i],side=:left)
    StatsPlots.violin!(X[i],B[i],side=:right)

end
current()
```

[figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIBbF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of writing it, as at the beginning, is as follows:

```
using StatsPlots
A=[rand(10), rand(12), rand(44)]
B=A./2
X = [[1],[2],[3]]
StatsPlots.violin(X,A,side=:left)
StatsPlots.violin!(X,B,side=:right)
```